# Best way to clear the std::vector array?

Tags: c++11, visual-c++, c++14

Which method is better and fast, and why?

```
for (unsigned int i=0; i<meshes.size(); i++)
{
    meshes.erase(meshes.begin() + i);
    if(meshes[i]) delete meshes[i];
}
```

or this one...

```
for (auto it = meshes.begin(); it != meshes.end(); ++it)
    delete *it;
meshes.clear();
```

Comment: Why do you store pointers in a vector? [What is "fast"](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)? What is "better"? Both are weird, slow and dangerous.

Comment: What's wrong with storing pointers in a vector?

Comment: The first snippet is completely broken. The second is slightly less broken.

Comment: @NRitH Nothing. I think Drop meant  "Why do you store _owning_ pointers _instead of plain objects_ in a vector?" or "Why do you use _raw owning_ pointers?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't quite know what you're trying to achieve with the first snippet, but the seconds snippet looks right and efficient assuming your data is in an `std::vector<Mesh*>`where each pointer is `new`ed

Answer (score 5):

Ideally, you have `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Mesh>> meshes;`, and then it's just `meshes.clear();`, or if possible, just `std::vector<Mesh>`!

Comment: *ideally*, `Mesh` wouldn't have to be dynamically allocated :p

Answer (score 1):

Might as well use Modern C++ syntax.

```
for (auto p: meshes) delete p;
meshes.clear();
```